# Problem in importing python libraries in the command prompt

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to write a simple program that uses the numpy module. I have downloaded it without the use of a virtual environment using pip. On doing a pip freeze all the modules are present yet I am unable to import it when I use the command prompt python terminal. I found a few answers related to the environment variables but I can't work my way around it.

[image: Here is the pip freeze modules]

[image: Here is the no module error]

Comment: Type in cosole `where pip` and `where python` then compare path to both apps.

Comment: please, post text as text!

Comment: Where python gave me three paths. 

where python:
C:\Program Files\Python\Python37\python.exe
C:\Users\shaurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
C:\Users\shaurya\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

where pip  : C:\Users\shaurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be caused by multiple python versions installed in your system.
So try:

```sh
python -m pip list
```

and if it does not list numpy, try installing it using:

```sh
python -m pip install numpy
```

In some cases, `py` works the same as `python`, so try all above things with `py` as well, including your own attempts

Comment: I needed admin permissions to install numpy but it worked just fine.

Comment: nice then! Edited the post, also check it.